# Content of low quality posts is shown as "1"

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

The content of several posts is shown as "1". These appear to all be candidate low quality posts with a negative score on the [review](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts?pagesize=15&filter=day) page:

[image]

Opening the post and clicking edit reveals the proper content. Why does this happen? Is it an attempt to stop Google indexing bad posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a little problem with some updates we were doing. It should be fixed now.